# Is my matic lost?

Tags: erc-20, wallets, polygon

Recently I sent erc20 matic from an eth wallet to an matic wallet address the tx was successful on etherscan but my sent amount or tx is not found in the destination matic address and or polyscan. Is it now lost?

Comment: Please add links to your transactions if you want us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have control of the address on polygon through metamask your matic is fine. Its just waiting for you at the same address but on mainnet, you can recover it by sending some ether to this address to pay for gas and then transferring it to an address you use (or bridge it to polygon using https://wallet.matic.network/bridge/)